# Convert 32-char md5 string to integer

Tags: hash, md5

What's the most efficient way to convert an md5 hash to a unique integer to perform a modulus operation?

Comment: Do you want to do hash % x or x % hash? In the first case you might not even need the entire hash to compute the answer.

Comment: I'm looking for hash % X

Comment: Have any of these answers been helpful or do you still need more insight?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since the solution language was not specified, Python is used for this example.

```py
import os
import hashlib

array = os.urandom(1 << 20)
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(array)
digest = md5.hexdigest()
number = int(digest, 16)

print(number % YOUR_NUMBER)
```

Comment: An md5 is 128 bits of information. A python int is generally going to be 32 or 64 bits of information, so converting to an int is going to throw away data, isn't it...? I'd think you need to use long.

Comment: Why do you convert it to base 16? Is that the convention?

Comment: @Nate The `hexdigest` method is convenient to use. Converting the string it returns into a number is equally easy to do with a call to `int`.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Thanks for the response - I wasn't asking about `hexdigest` vs `int`, but more base 16 as opposed to base 10 or base 2 for example. I tried out a few different options, and it seems like the hash will convert to an integer with a base of 16 or higher, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: @Nate Let's talk computer theory (right or wrong). Integers are stored as bits in a computer (base 2). However, the base they are stored in does not matter as much as the baseless value the integer represents. When you want to see an integer, you can display it in any base you want using any characters you want. In many cases, you can forget about the base of a number and just think about its value. How you express that value depends on the base you think in or the base you want to display it with, but the basic of math pretty much just work without regard to the base of a number.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - that is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what platform you're running on, or what the format of this hash is. Presumably it's hex, so you've got 16 bytes of information.

In order to convert that to a *unique* integer, you basically need a 16-byte (128-bit) integer type. Many platforms don't have such a type available natively, but you could use two `long` values in C# or Java, or a `BigInteger` in Java or .NET 4.0.

Conceptually you need to parse the hex string to bytes, and then convert the bytes into an integer (or two). The most efficient way of doing that will entirely depend on which platform you're using.

Comment: You'd be looking at sscanf in PHP: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php

Answer (score 2):

There is more data in a MD5 than will fit in even a 64b integer, so there's no way (without knowing what platform you are using) to get a unique integer. You can get a somewhat unique one by converting the hex version to several integers worth of data then combining them (addition or multiplication). How exactly you would go about that depends on what language you are using though.

Alot of language's will implement either an `unpack` or `sscanf` function, which are good places to start looking.

Comment: You're assuming that "integer" is limited to 64 bits. What about BigInteger?

Comment: Of course, but alot of platforms don't have arbitrary length integers. Depends entirely on what platform you are on as to if there is a (native) BigInteger implementation.

Comment: Absolutely, but "it depends on your platform" is not the same as "there's no way" :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is modulus, you don't actually need to convert it to 128-byte integer. You can go digit by digit or byte by byte, like this.

```
mod=0
for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
   digit=md5[i]; //I presume you can convert chart to digit yourself.
   mod=(mod*16+digit) % divider;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define your own hash function that converts an MD5 string into an integer of the desired width.  If you want to interpret the MD5 hash as a plain string, you can try the [FNV](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-1) algorithm.  It's pretty quick and fairly evenly distributed.