# Numeric Representation of an Object in Python

Tags: python, random

I basically want to convert a Python object into a fixed length numeric (not alphanumeric) value. One way, I've come up with is,

```
import random
x = Car(brand='toyota', model='corolla', price='10000', year=1997)
random.seed(x)

random.random()
0.13436424411240122

random.seed(x)
random.random()
0.13436424411240122
```

I'm wondering if there is more convenient and generic way (or library) to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're now using is:

- Prone to typo error in your `Car` object.
- Fragile if you forget to call `random.seed()` every time.
- Case sensitive.

Also, if I were you, I'd like to have a little control on how my number is generated.

The other answers have already showed to you the existence of [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/hashlib.html).

I would probably use it like this:

```
class Car:
    # ...
    def __hash__(self):
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        for i in ('brand', 'model', 'price', 'year'):
            attr = getattr(self, i)
            md5.update(str(attr).lowercase())
        return int(md5.hexdigest(), 16)
```

---

Reference on the integer conversion: [Convert 32-char md5 string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1779879/1132524).

Answer (score 1):

```
def convertObjectIntoFixedLengthNumeric(obj):
    return 17

x = Car(brand='toyota', model='corolla', price='10000', year=1997)
convertObjectIntoFixedLengthNumeric(x)
17
```

Very convenient and generic. If not what you were looking for, provide some more information..

Comment: `def random(): return 6 # number generated by random dice roll, guaranteed to be random.` (edit: damn you @thg435)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the built-in [`id`-function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id). It returns the memory adress of an object *which is always unique*, as long as you do not compare the id of an already garbage collected object.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the attributes you care about and hash them.

```
class Car(...):
   ...
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.brand, self.model, self.price, self.year))

 ...

print hash(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre talking about a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). I think you need to give more info as to what you need this for to get helpful answers.